# How to install mongodb on Debian 11 (bullseye)?

Tags: debian, mongodb

How should i install MongoDB on debian 11? There nothing about debian 11 on mongo docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ what should i do?

Comment: Debian 11 is pretty new and they probably haven't updated the docs yet. Computing for Geeks has an [installation guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mongodb-on-debian-linux/) that looks pretty similar. Give it a shot.

Comment: i already tried this
after
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl enable mongod
steps when i try to do mongod --version
shows: Illegal instruction

Comment: Try going back to MongoDB 4.4 and see if this error still shows up.